# how to make a predictive trajectory arc while aiming?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a trajectory arc that would predict the trajectory path of the object, the drag and shoot seem fine but the arc is not working. initially I used an arrow for showing the direction of the movement of the object but later I tried to do the same using an array which would store 2 points and would keep updating after every iteration and it would result in an arc since I used the equations of motion to predict the positions after each frame.

```
    ***
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movement: MonoBehaviour
{
    public float velocity;
    float time;
    float x;
    float y;
    float tt;
    float g;
    Vector2 force;
    public float power = 2.0f;
    Vector3 startpoint;
    Vector3 endpoint;
    Camera cam;
    public Vector2 maxpower;
    public Vector2 minpower;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    Vector3 currentposition;
    Vector3 sp;
    LineRenderer lr;
    int resolution = 10;
    Vector3 newpoint;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        time = 0f;
        g = Mathf.Abs(Physics2D.gravity.y);
        cam = Camera.main;
        lr = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        time += Time.deltaTime;
        x = gameObject.transform.position.x + velocity * time;
        tt = time * time;
        y = gameObject.transform.position.y + (g * tt) / 2f;
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            startpoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            startpoint.z = 5;
        }
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            sp = new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x, gameObject.transform.position.y, 5);
            currentposition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            currentposition.z = 5;
            LineRenderer(sp);
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            endpoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            endpoint.z = 5;
            force = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(startpoint.x - endpoint.x, minpower.x, maxpower.x), Mathf.Clamp(startpoint.y - endpoint.y, minpower.y, maxpower.y));
            rb.AddForce(force * power, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            x = x + velocity * time;
            y = y + (g * tt) / 2f;
            EndLine();
        }
    }
    public void LineRenderer(Vector3 p)
    {
        lr.positionCount = resolution;
        Vector3 arc = p;
        for(int i=0;i<resolution;i++)
        {
            newpoint = calculate(arc, i / (float)resolution);
            lr.SetPosition(i, newpoint);
            arc = newpoint;
        }
    }
    public Vector3 calculate(Vector3 point, float t)
    {
        point.x += velocity * t;
        point.y += 0.5f * g * t * t;
        return point;
    }
    public void EndLine()
    {
        lr.positionCount = 0;
    }
}

    ***
```

This the code, any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DUmpVi82q8&t=349s

Comment: watch this, it may be useful

Answer (score 0):

A bug that I see is your delta-time:

You call `Calculate(arc, i/resolution)`, with `i` and `resolution` both being integers.

The parameter might be `float time`, but C# will first calculate `i/resolution` as an integer division, then convert the result to float. The result will be zero as long as `i` is less than `resolution`.

Change it to: `i/(float)resolution` to force a floating-point division.

Comment: Hey, I tried that and now I am getting an arc but then it is fixed for any direction, it is not updating with every drag, and is the same for any force or duration of drag. Can u help me further with this problem.
Thanks